# How to rewrite `let*` in terms of `lambda`?

Tags: scheme, lambda

I understand how `(let ((x v1) (y v2)) e)` can be rewritten as `((lambda (x y) e) v1 v2)`. But I'm not too familiar with `let*`.

How can we rewrite `(let* ((x v1) (y v2) (z v3)) e)` in terms of lambda and function applications?

Comment: To the folks who have downvoted this question: This is a good, fundamental question about Scheme that any beginner is likely to want answered. It might be a homework question, but I think it's of sufficiently general interest that we should answer it definitively so people can find it on the web easily. If you agree, please retract your downvotes. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This `let` expression:

```
(let ((x v1)
      (y v2))
  e)
```

Is equivalent to the following `lambda` application, noticing that in here the variables can be evaluated in any order (no strict left-to-right order is enforced) and the definition of one variable can not reference the variables before it:

```
((lambda (x y)
   e)
 v1 v2)
```

On the other hand, this `let*` expression:

```
(let* ((x v1)
       (y v2)
       (z v3))
  e)
```

Can be transformed into a series of nested `lambda`s, in a way that ensures that the variables are evaluated in the same order that was used to define them, and the ones defined first can be referenced in all subsequent definitions:

```
((lambda (x)
   ((lambda (y)
      ((lambda (z)
         e)
       v3))
    v2))
 v1)
```

Another example: this code will only work if we use the second transformation:

```
(let* ((x 1)
       (y (+ x 1)))
  (+ x y))
```

As you can see, the definition of `y` references `x`, only in this way will it work:

```
((lambda (x)
   ((lambda (y)
      (+ x y))
    (+ x 1)))
 1)
```

Finally, here are two great online books for learning Scheme:

- [How to Design Programs](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/)
- [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html)

Comment: How is this different from ((lambda (x y z) e) v1 v2 v3)? Or is this invalid?

Comment: That's just the first case again (a `let`). It's completely different from the second case, because in the code you just posted as a comment the variables can be evaluated in any order (not in strict left-to-right order as in a `let*`), and one variable can not reference the others that were defined before it

Comment: I updated my answer with yet another example and some clarifications, please re-read it ;)

Comment: I also updated my answer with an example, that doesn't invoke undefined behaviour. :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation (and the sources)! This helped so much!

Answer (score 1):

`let*` is simply nested `let` instances. For example,

```
(let* ((x v1)
       (y v2)
       (z v3))
  e)
```

is the same as

```
(let ((x v1))
  (let ((y v2))
    (let ((z v3))
      e)))
```

Does that help with your understanding of `let*`? :-)

Update: The OP is asking (in comments to Óscar's post) how `let*` is different from `let`. Here is an example: first, let's use `let*`:

```
(let ((x 42))
  (let* ((x 10)
         (y (+ x 13)))
    y))
```

This returns 23 (10 + 13). The value of the inner `x` is used, and the value of the outer `x` is shadowed.

Now, let's look at what happens if we used `let` instead of `let*`:

```
(let ((x 42))
  (let ((x 10)
        (y (+ x 13)))
    y))
```

This returns 55 (42 + 13). The value of the inner `x` is not used in computing the value of `y`; it only takes effect inside the body of the `let`.

Comment: I see. So if one were to code: 
(let* ((x 42))
  (let* ((x 10)
    (y (+ x 13))) y)) 
Does this also result to 23(10 + 13)?

Comment: Yes, but I encourage you to actually try it out. :-)

Answer (score 1):

### What `let*` expands to

This:

```
(let* ([a 1] [b (* 2 a)])
  (cons a b))
```

expands to this:

```
((lambda (a)
   ((lambda (b)
      (cons a b))
    (* 2 a)))
 1)
```

Here's a nice way to think of what `lambda` means in Scheme (nice because it's both simple and accurate): it's both a label for a place in the program *and* a scope for bound variables. In Scheme, a label for a place in the program (like what you can `goto` to in other languages or branch to in machine language) always goes with a scope for bound variables. You can only "goto" a place in the program by supplying values to bind to the variables bound within its scope.

Scheme's `let` is a way of saying, "I want to make a scope where these variables are bound, but I don't want to wait until later to tell their values. I want to specify their values right here." So, `let` is just a macro that makes the lambda and then supplies the values right there.

If you want the values of one of the variables to be an expression that uses another of the variables, like the way `b` is expressed in terms of `a` above, then `b` has to be defined within the scope of `a`. Hence the `let*` macro, which defines each successive variable in a scope that includes the previous variable. Since we have a bunch of nested scopes, they are implemented by a bunch of nested lambdas.

### The macro

Here's how to tell Scheme how to rewrite a `let*` as a bunch of nested lambdas and function applications:

```
(define-syntax let*
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(__ () body ...)
      (begin body ...)]
    [(__ ([v e] [v* e*] ...) body ...)
      ((lambda (v)
         (let* ([v* e*] ...)
           body ...))
       e)]))

(let* ([a 1] [b (* 2 a)])
  (cons a b))
=> (1 . 2)
```

In [Chez Scheme](http://www.scheme.com/petitechezscheme.html), you can play around with this in the REPL by typing `(expand '(let* ([a 1] [b (* 2 a)]) (cons a b))` and seeing what comes out. Here's what comes out when I try it:

```
(let ([#:a 1]) (let ([#:b (#2%* 2 #:a)]) (#2%cons #:a #:b)))
```